# Concatenate Values in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to concatenate values in excel by recording a macro to automate a command for a set of values but can't seem to figure out how to reloop and keep it going for the set.

Concatenate needs to get done in a specific portion of the text before the suffix. Recorded macro is only reading the cell rather than the location so I can't run it with different values or text.

[image: data sample]

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55106056/edit) to include the code you ahve so far as well as a clear explanation what what nees to be looped?

Comment: Is this always the same closing tags?  You could do with splitting the closing and opening tags out, but based on what you have, you can do the following formula `=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-5) & CONCATENATE("<LI>",B1,"</LI> ") & CONCATENATE("<LI>",C1,"</LI> ") & RIGHT(A1,5)` more info is needed for code advice on it.

Comment: Yes, always the same opening and closing tags.

Comment: Range("B2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "<ul> <li>Hello </li> <LI>A: Goodbye </LI><ul> "
    Range("C2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "<ul> <li>Hello </li> <LI>A: Goodbye </LI><LI>B: Sun </LI><ul> "
    Range("B2").Select

Comment: If it's always the same code, I'd recommend the answer I gave below

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm assuming, but I'm guessing you're going to have the same tags for each Set?

If that's the case, I would recommend just turning your range into a `Table` and using this formula, which will copy down

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question concerning trying to record a macro, you don't actually need to perform a loop, you can use vba to place the formula directly into each cell in the range. So, Piggybacking off of @Gary's Student, here is a one-liner using his formula.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=A1 & B1 & ""</li><ul>"" & C1 & ""</li><ul>"""
```

You will need to change your worksheet to meet your needs.